# Share session variables in websphere portal

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal

does anyone know how to share session variables and recover from any portlet in websphere portal, for example I set a session variable (Object) in one portlet and i want to get the value of that variable. How can i do this?.

I'm using Websphere portal 8, and my IDE is RAD 8.5

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If your portlets are deployed in the same webapp, you can use the PortletSession with the scope APPLICATION : portletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("name", "value", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE).

Otherwise, you need to create your own sharing service that will store variables. It seems that this article could help you : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0602_hepper/0602_hepper.html

Comment: Hi Thomas, i already saw the link, but i have problems with the version of Portal , because there are some classes deprecated for portal 8. Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share objects / state across portlets that are not in the same web module (war file) and you are in WebSphere Portal, you can use a WebSphere Application Server proprietary service called DynaCache. It is mature and commonly used.  You can set up a Map object that is shared not only across portlets (really any application code in the same JVM), but can also be set up to share objects across JVMs (like in a cluster).  Key programming interface: [DistributedMap](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/cache/DistributedMap.html). Here's a pretty good [blog post](http://wsportaltutorials.blogspot.com/2012/03/implementing-websphere-dynacache.html) on setting up a cache instance so your portlets can each look the map up via JNDI and either get or put to it just like any other `Map<K,V>`.

Comment: Scotth i have a question, what happens if i share an object, all users session can see it? Regards

Comment: Dynacache is just a big Map. The keys will be of your choosing. If you use session id string as a key or perhaps username (caches across all logins with same ID), then the Map will be like a "super session" and data visible across modules or jvms.